# Cannot load static images in react native android

Tags: react-native

I recently started to integrate react native in an already existing android app. I have tried multiple image loading styles as mentioned on the page https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html

Method 1(Hybrid Apps): For android use `<Image source={{uri: 'asset:/app_icon.png'}} style={{width: 40, height: 40}} />`
This method doesn't load anything on the app, just a 40X40 empty area is loaded.

Method 2: `<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />`
I used the absolute path to the image `app/res/drawable-hdpi/image.png` but it didn't work either.

Got the error

```
Unable to resolve module `../app/res/drawable-hdpi/image.png` from 
`/Users/MyName/StudioProjects/reatProject/android/react-native/index.js`: could not resolve 
`/Users/MyName/StudioProjects/reatProject/android/app/res/drawable-hdpi/image.png' as a file nor as a folder
```

I always provide height and width attributes in style map.

My project structure is

```
android/
  app/
    res/
    src/
    tests/
  react-native/
    index.js
    package.json
    package.lock.json
  tests/
  build.gradle
```

The project `build.gradle` file has the maven repository included as maven `{ url "$rootDir/react-native/node_modules/react-native/android" }`

I had posted this as an issue on react native github issues, but got no solution there, so asking here if anyone has been through the same issue. I am fairly new to react native so maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's going on, but the folder structure seems a bit weird. Usually you should have stuff inside your react-folder in the root folder, along with src, android, node_modules etc.

Comment: Try moving to a general folder structure and it might fix things for you since, files and images are linked using relative path and they have a default common path they look for. Good luck and let me know how it turns out.

Comment: Right, the movement of folder structure is something that we want to keep this way. Even keeping the original structure, the one that's recommended by react native, I can only use require with an absolute path to the images in the particular drawable folder, say drawable-hdpi. Still doesn't solve the images correctly loading for all screens. Even then the `asset:/` scheme doesn't seem to work. We don't want to move all the assets to a separate react asset folder with @2x and @3x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had ended up making a mistake. The image source has to be of the form `{{uri:"name"}}` and I kept writing {{`uri:"name.png"`}}. It doesn't accept png in this scheme, but in the `asset://` and the `require` scheme, it does. Its just a bit confusing.

For anyone facing the same issue, the same directory structure would work, just use image this way, and avoid using the extension.

```
<Image source={{uri:"imageName"}} style={{height:100, width:100}}/>
```